# Where is IPasswordProvider for WSE services?

Tags: .net, web-services, wse

I can't find IPasswordProvider interface in my WSE project.

I want to create a custom password provider so I have to implement this interface.

Which namespace is it in?

In VS.NET, I can't find Microsoft.Web.Services.Security anywhere?

**Update**
I found  Microsoft.Web.Services3, is that .net 3.5 or it still works in .net 2.0?

But I can't find the interface in Services3??

Comment: WSE is obsolete. All new web service work should be done using WCF, and existing WSE code should be migrated or retired ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using version 2 or later of WSE.  The IPasswordProvider interface was made obsolete from version 2 on.  See here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms827740.aspx